# How to resource the itcl classes to without starting a tcl shell

Tags: tcl, itcl

With this Tcl script: `A.tcl`

```
itcl::class ::A {
    variable list1 {}
    public method getList {} {
        return $list1
    } 
}
```

I do this:

- Start the tcl shell and interactively do `source A.tcl`
- then make changes to `getList` method in `A.tcl`
- To make the changes effective, I do re-`source` the file `A.tcl`
- When I re-`source`, I get the following error

```
% source /home/manid/scripts/test.tcl
class "A" already exists
```

How can i overcome this error? Is there a way to get the latest changes in the class definition without exiting the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your code somewhat differently. In particular, you have to put the definitions of the body of the methods (which *can* be repeated) outside the declaration of the class (which can't be repeated). Then, you do a conditional class creation (with `itcl::is class` as the tester) and use `itcl::body` to actually provide the method definitions.

According to these principles, rewriting your `A.tcl` to be:

```
if {![itcl::is class ::A]} {
    itcl::class ::A {
        variable list1 {}
        # *Dummy* method body; method must exist, but may be empty
        public method getList {} {}
    }
}

itcl::body ::A::getList {} {
    return $list1
}
```

would allow you to `source` that multiple times to change the method bodies however you wanted. This doesn't give you freedom to change everything (e.g., the variable declarations and scope rules are fixed); you need to switch to something like TclOO to get that sort of flexibility.